# How to exclude interaction effect in linear regression modelling?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, experiment-design

I am working with biological dataset. I am looking for significantly differentially expressed genes that stand out under effect of 3 different factors (e.x.  gut microbiota level has/not,  tissue, Lcells has/not). The data is not good so I cannot perform normal ANOVA test to measure effect of all factors at once. So I have done linear regression modeling for each factor separately. Then I compare all one-way linear regression and found those genes that were significantly expressed only in one factor comparison (e.x. only based on having or not having gut microbiota) were selected. Now I am curious to know if I can clam these are significantly expressed by effect of this factor (e.g. gut microbiota)? Because I know in ANOVA test there is also one test for interaction which I might don’t have it here!

Comment: In what way is the data "not good"?

Comment: Actually they are not clustered very well. And if I perform ANOVA approximately no significant gene I would get. I think it should be because of fewer number of replicates.

Comment: ANOVA is linear regression so I'm confused on what you're doing.

Comment: Some clarifying questions: 
1) Is your dependent variable continuous or categorical (if categorical, is there a logical ordering)?
2) Are there multiple dependent variables? For instance, are there multiple genes that can be expressed, and you are trying to predict which among many are expressed?
3) Are your independent variables continuous or categorical? For instance, gut microbiota level sounds continuous, but then you put has/has not, implying it is binary.
4) Can you further explain "not clustered very well?" Is this a visual analysis or did you do some measurements/tests?

Answer (score 1):

ANOVA is global hypothesis testing: In a certain broad model (the assumptions) and a special set of parameters in this model (the hypothesis), do data like the ones observed belong to rare extreme cases? Then reject the hypothesis. The global test acts like a judge. One tolerates a certain error probability: If the hypothesis is true, we may err with a probability $\leq \alpha$.

What you want is to find certain genes. Your procedure is intended to act like the police: find the suspects, but don't arrest the whole town. In the field of studying gene expressions, one uses multiple testing procedures; preferably controlling the false discovery rate (FDR) but sometimes also controlling the family wise error rate (FWER). This is the analog to $\alpha$.

Now you know that your specimens were affected by possibly interacting factors and most gene finding procedures don't adress that.

I would do a factorial anova for each gene seperately going sequentially from test on interaction to test on the main effects until you find something significant. Then I would put together the results using a FDR/FWER procedure. You'll probably find some genes that were differentially expressed disregarding the other effects (and interactions) and you'll probably find some genes where you cannot clearly state an overall difference in expression because there are interactions. You would have to think about them separately.

Note that if you would not have identified the factorial structure, you could have erroneously identified such genes as overall differentially expressed just because of the given number ratio of specimens in the factor combinations. So the identification of the factorial structure is a clear advantage for the qualitiy of your study.

Unfortunately, I don't know which kind of multiple testing procedure would have best power if there is that kind of factorial model "inside it".

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

1. Subtract mean
2. Ridge regression
3. principal component methods
4. some other regression method for handling highly co-linear data.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @youglau. I think it would help the OP even more if you could elaborate on these methods a little bit & explain how they address the problem, what their pros & cons are, perhaps add some pointers to where the OP can get more information on them, etc.

Comment: Thanks Younglau for your answer. Yes I think it would be perfect if you explain a bit more about each.

Comment: The OP doesn't seem to understand the that regression is a special case of ANOVA, so I doubt ridge regression or PCA will help.  Depending on the additional information sought by @le_andrew, I'm guessing a simple multiple regression with interaction terms will work just fine.